# Can somebody explain the following texture behaviour to me?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I'm trying to write a simple class to set the data in a 1D Texture. I have a header, a body and a main file. The texture lookup runs correctly if the `Atmosphere::initialize()` function is defined in the `main` file. It does not work correctly if the `Atmosphere::intitialize()` function is defined in the `Atmosphere.cu` file.

```
//    Atmosphere.h

texture<float4, cudaTextureType1D, cudaReadModeElementType> Atmospheres;

class Atmosphere {
public:
    Atmosphere() {
    }

    void initialize();
};
```

This is the `Atmosphere.cu` file.

```
// Atmosphere.cu

void Atmosphere::initialize()  {
    // omitted for brevity, setting up a 1D texture
}
```

And the `main.cu` file:

```
int main(void) {

    Atmosphere atmo;
    atmo.initialize();

    // cuda stuff

    queryAtmosphere<<<1, 1>>>(altitude, d_out);

    cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, sizeof(float4), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    std::cout << *h_out << std::endl;

    // cuda stuff

}
```

---

If I put the definition for `Atmosphere::initialize()` in the `main.cu` file, the output is:

```
x: 1.25, y: 300, z: 60, w: -60
```

But if I leave the definition in the `Atmosphere.cu` file, the result is:

```
x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0
```

This seems like a trivial and benign change to make to the code, but it has dire consequences. I'm confused why defining the `initialize()` function in a separate file is causing the lookup error.

Why is this? I've poured over the `texture` literature and done many examples, but none directly address this behaviour. It seems odd that a function definition in the `main` file would behave differently than one defined in the `Atmosphere.cu` file.

**Note:**

I've left out a lot of the CUDA specific code for brevity. I'm more concerned with the confusing behaviour rather than the specific CUDA syntax.

Comment: Unless you compile with separate compilation enabled, CUDA has no device code linker. Textures and the code that use them must be declared at the same compilation unit scope. Otherwise strange things happen. Like this.

Comment: @talonmies How would one use "separate compilation enabled" in the `nvcc` call? Is it a flag?

Comment: Ah got it: http://www.google.com/url?q=http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2012/presentations/gpu-object-linking.pdf&sa=U&ei=oDzLUc2WAZfK4AORiIGIBw&ved=0CBgQFjAA&sig2=9BwsXzOg__oFC7VHV650FQ&usg=AFQjCNHnMenJIFlSLCqFHX6s2uzCAUYKLQ